Keys in Payload Instagram GraphQL
I'm studying GraphQL, and I recently discovered that Instagram uses it for their API requests. I've been trying to learn more about it, but there are some things I can't figure out on my own.
When I open DevTools and navigate to the Network tab, then refresh a link that leads to a public user profile, I see various requests being made. Among them is a GraphQL request that retrieves the data displayed on the front-end. I've been trying to understand the information in the payload and where it originates from, but I'm struggling to do so on my own.
I've tried searching through the Meta Documentation, but I couldn't find any relevant information there. I'm just attempting to understand what the information in the payload represents and where it originates from.
Could someone please help me with this?

"I've tried searching through the Meta Documentation, but I couldn't find any relevant information there." - that's because there they are documenting the APIs that external app developers can use. Their internal APIs, that provide the data for the website or their own, native apps, are not covered.
